# getting following error "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: android, r.java-file

I recently update android sdk and having following error `R cannot be resolved to a variable`.
I cleaned and build project but `R file` still missing. i also install `Android SDK build tools` but R cannot be resolved. How can I resolve this problem. I saw another articles but these wasn't help me.

Comment: Check the Image Name and check the layout/xyz.xml and string.xml

Comment: Clean your project and check if any errors are shown in the errors tab..by looking there further steps can be taken..There will be many situations where this error might arise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved issues in my android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144782/r-cannot-be-resolved-issues-in-my-android-project)

Comment: I checked my layout/xyz.xml and string.xml file. and clean project and build project and again i didn't fine R.java file in my gen folder

Comment: Finally i resolve the error. The error was in my string.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the version from 2.2 to 4.4 or whatever then clean the project and the error will be removed.

Comment: where i have to change the version 2.2 to 4.4