# Making custom Android keyboard via Eclipse tutorial; errors about R references won't go away

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I guess I can't follow [these instructions](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) (but I've never used Eclipse before).

Here's my Eclipse Luna (2; 4.4.2) project structure, including a look at the file (`SimpleIME.java`) with the two errors (`R cannot be resolved to a variable`) (I have cleaned the project; rebuilding is automatic.):

[image]

There are two identical `AndroidManifest.xml` files. One that I created and one that Eclipse (or whatever) created.

[image]

The project has no Activity by design but Eclipse created one anyway, so I deleted it (with preview; only one reference (itself) was found).

Here's `R.layout.keyboard`:

[image]

Here's `R.xml.qwerty`:

[image]

So... **what should I do?** I cut and pasted entire contents of files and even file names, so typos shouldn't be the culprit, but maybe the structure is messed up. There's no structure shown at this otherwise excellent tutorial (first link).

Comment: The [r] tag is for the statistical computer language.

Comment: @BondedDust--Oops. It was a suggested tag! But I should have read about it. Thanks for editing.

Comment: If you are new to Eclipse, you might not have tried this yet: have you tried restarting Eclipse yet? You should do this right after cleaning the project.

Comment: Also, it might be the tiny screen I'm trying to view your screenshots on, but it looks like your AndroidManifest.xml contains an invalid apostrophe (or a similar character) right at the very end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Eclipse and also Android Studio has problems to resolve the `R` resources if there is somewhere an exception.

Save all your classes and try to clean and build again. Normally it should give you an exception which resource is wrong. (Any image with wrong name, upper case name of image, any .xml file with exceptions.)

The cause is that the Android tools can only compile and create the `R` file if it is able to resolve all resources, and their identifiers.

If you tried clean and build. please post the error which will occur. (I made the experience that Eclipse has some issues to show the error marker on the specific resource file)

On a side note: Why do you still use Eclipse?

Comment: Wonderful. New Clean and I get TWO MORE `R` errors, on lines that DO NOT REFER TO `R`!!

Comment: @DSlomer64 you have saved everything in a state which should be compileable? if yes look inside your resource files. `.xml`s and look for errors.

Comment: Side note: because the "tutorial" is based on Eclipse. I'm starting over. It won't take long. I had errors and misplaced xml files in the original effort, which I moved, probably asking for trouble. I have never liked Eclipse. AS has it beat hands down. I never gave Eclipse a fair trial. This is it. If this effort fails, I'll try to fake it in AS.

Comment: @DSlomer64 which also helped a lot of times for me was to check all .xml files and look for errors. sometimes just the marker did not show up.

Comment: Look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546749/android-eclipse-moving-project-caused-all-r-reference-errors) and you'll never use Eclipse. It's the new problem as I try to recreate the danged thing. I'm getting "Premature end of file" in qwerty.xml which is supposed to be in res\xml but no matter how I create it, eclipse gripes. What crappy software.

Comment: How I fixed the "premature" error: save the file, error and all--and the error goes away. Good ol' Eclipse.

Comment: And I got the same `R` errors BUT THIS TIME I got popup help with two "quick fix" options: import Android.R (NO!) and import R from this project. No `R` errors at this time.

Comment: No `R` errors :D so it's solved. And no i don't use Eclipse. Just Android Studio ;)

Comment: So. No errors; selected Run | Run; nothing happened; selected Run | Debug and got activity; eventually selected Run | Run; console says `\SimpleKeyboard\bin\SimpleKeyboard.apk installed on device`; I follow link's instructions to click Settings | Language and Input on the device; but SimpleKeyboard isn't an option. I guess I should start a new Question........

Comment: @DSlomer64 yes. This should be a new question.

Comment: I solved the problem by using Android Studio. Took 30 minutes. Refer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143971/creating-custom-android-keyboard-from-well-known-link-compiles-installs-but-n/30144986#30144986). Back to "side note": I'm deleting Eclipse from my PC right now!

Comment: @DSlomer64 great decision ;)